# What is MobileTearSheet and where is it?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

What is MobileTearSheet and where is it?
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By all means copy the one from the docs site. (it's just an image.)

Take it:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/callemall/material-ui/master/docs/src/app/components/MobileTearSheet.js

Answer (score 6):

Here is my working version (in one file) you can drop into you project.

> If you want to use this source, please up vote this answer

**MobileTearSheet.js**

```
import React, from 'react';

const MobileTearSheet = React.createClass({

getDefaultProps() {
    return { height: "100%" }
},
render:function() {

const styles = {
  root: {
    marginBottom: 24,
    marginRight: 24,
    maxWidth: 360,
    width: '100%',
  },
  container: {
    border: 'solid 1px #d9d9d9',
    borderBottom: 'none',
    height: this.props.height,
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  bottomTear: {
    display: 'block',
    position: 'relative',
    marginTop: -10,
    maxWidth: 360,
  },
};

return (
  <div style={Object.assign({},styles.root,this.props.style||{})}>
    <div style={styles.container}>
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
    <div style={styles.bottomTear}>
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 360 10" enableBackground="new 0 0 360 10">
        <polygon fill="#DAD9D9" points={`359,0 359,7.5 352.5,0.5 345,8.5 337.5,0.5 330,8.5 322.5,0.5 315,8.5 307.5,0.5 300,8.5 292.5,0.5
            285,8.5 277.5,0.5 270,8.5 262.5,0.5 255,8.5 247.5,0.5 240,8.5 232.5,0.5 225,8.5 217.5,0.5 210,8.5 202.5,0.5 195,8.5 187.5,0.5
            180,8.5 172.5,0.5 165,8.5 157.5,0.5 150,8.5 142.5,0.5 135,8.5 127.5,0.5 120,8.5 112.5,0.5 105,8.5 97.5,0.5 90,8.5 82.5,0.5
            75,8.5 67.5,0.5 60,8.5 52.5,0.5 45,8.5 37.5,0.5 30,8.5 22.5,0.5 15,8.5 7.5,0.5 1,7.5 1,0 0,0 0,10 7.5,2 15,10 22.5,2 30,10
            37.5,2 45,10 52.5,2 60,10 67.5,2 75,10 82.5,2 90,10 97.5,2 105,10 112.5,2 120,10 127.5,2 135,10 142.5,2 150,10 157.5,2 165,10
            172.5,2 180,10 187.5,2 195,10 202.5,2 210,10 217.5,2 225,10 232.5,2 240,10 247.5,2 255,10 262.5,2 270,10 277.5,2 285,10
            292.5,2 300,10 307.5,2 315,10 322.5,2 330,10 337.5,2 345,10 352.5,2 360,10 360,0 `}/>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
);
  }
})

export default MobileTearSheet;
```

**For usage see: [material-ui list example](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/list)**

Answer (score 1):

I found this question while debugging why the List example code wasn't compiling. Don't worry you can just replace the  tags with a  and it should work just fine!